# Spring Boot - Parameter of constructor required a single bean, but multiple were found for Generated ApiClient Constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm working on a Spring Boot application and I'm getting an error related to multiple beans being found for generated ApiClient constructor.
The error message says:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.xxx.client.xxx.accounts.ApiClient required a single bean, but 5 were found:
- accessTokenRestTemplate: defined by method 'accessTokenRestTemplate' in class path resource [com/XXX/XXX/communication/http/HttpCommunicationConfiguration$OAuth2ClientConfiguration.class]
- interServiceRestTemplate: defined by method 'interServiceRestTemplate' in class path resource [com/XXX/XXX/communication/http/HttpCommunicationConfiguration.class]
- fdsRestTemplate: defined by method 'fdsRestTemplate' in class path resource [XXX/configuration/ApiRestTemplateOpenApiAutoConfiguration.class]
- pfRestTemplate: defined by method 'pfRestTemplate' in class path resource [XXX/openapi/common/configuration/ApiRestTemplateOpenApiAutoConfiguration.class]
- clientRestTemplate: defined by method 'clientRestTemplate' in class path resource [XXX/client/resttemplate/configuration/ClientHttpConfiguration.class]
```

Basically, my generated ApiClient has a constructor

```
    public ApiClient() {
        this.restTemplate = buildRestTemplate();
        init();
    }

    @Autowired
    public ApiClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        init();
    }
```

The error points this generated ApiClient and I believe it's because of this constructor.
I am using 'EnableAutoConfiguration' feature and I have the configuration class;

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({SecurityProperties.class, OrchestrationProperties.class})
@Slf4j
public class LimitApiRestTemplateAutoConfiguration {
    public static final String ACCOUNT_API_CLIENT = "accountApiClient";

    /**
     * Create the limits {@link ApiClient} client.
     *
     * @param fdsRestTemplate The fds {@code RestTemplate}.
     * @param properties      The {@code OrchestrationProperties}.
     * @return The {@code ApiClient}.
     */
    @Bean
    @Qualifier(ACCOUNT_API_CLIENT)
    public ApiClient accountApiClient(@Qualifier("fdsRestTemplate") RestTemplate fdsRestTemplate,
                                          LimitApiOrchestrationProperties properties) {
        log.info("Creating limitsApiClient, properties: {}", properties);

        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(fdsRestTemplate);
        apiClient.setBasePath(properties.getLimitsBaseUrl());

        return apiClient;
    }
```

I tried to use Qualifier to use 'fdsRestTemplate' bean, but it didn't work. I am still getting the error.

I also tried to override the ApiClient by using ApiClient.mustache, but it's really hard.

What I am missing here? I can provide more details, the ApiClient is generated with an OpenApi Generator.

Comment: `@Qualifier`/ your config *is the way* to fix the cited problem, but the error message points to constructor... If you plan to re-generate often, you *should* (in any case you *can*) use your config only, and exclude `ApiClient` from "component scanning". Alternatively you could "appropriate" the generated code... (I.e. making it "regular, versioned source", improving to your needs...but switching from "API first" to "code next" approach:)

Comment: @xerx593 Unfortunately, there is no chance for me to change the approach on a short-notice since it's a huge project. This ApiClient will be generated for each deployment. I tried to override ApiClient with a custom mustache template, but since there isn't any clear documentation about how to override the constructor, I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be able to solve my problems by writing a custom mvn module with the ApiClient mustache template.
If you are wondering how is the constructor in this template;

````
    public ApiClient({{#restTemplateBeanName}}@Qualifier("{{restTemplateBeanName}}") {{/restTemplateBeanName}}RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        init();
    }
```Generator class

public class RGenerator extends JavaClientCodegen {

    public static final String NAME = "R";
    public static final String REST_TEMPLATE_BEAN_NAME = "restTemplateBeanName";

    protected String restTemplateBeanName;

    protected String propertiesConfigName;

    public CodegenType getTag() {
      return CodegenType.CLIENT;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return NAME;
    }

    public String getHelp() {
      return "Generates a R client library.";
    }

    public RGenerator() {
        super();
        this.cliOptions.add(CliOption.newString(REST_TEMPLATE_BEAN_NAME, "An optional RestTemplate bean name"));
    }

    @Override
    public void processOpts() {
        super.processOpts();
        setTemplateDir(NAME);
        if (RESTTEMPLATE.equals(getLibrary())) {
            this.restTemplateBeanName = (String) this.additionalProperties.get(REST_TEMPLATE_BEAN_NAME);
        }

    }
````